# command for writing a sequence of numbers

Tags: macros, loops

While writing a document with many sequences of numbers (and various lower and upper boundaries), I would like to define a command such as `\myscale{1}{6}` that would produce:

```
1  2  3  4  5  6
```

What I am wondering is how to create the `while` loop that would write numbers until the value given by the second argument has been reached... Any idea ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With no package, only classical TeX:

```
\newcount\tmpnum
\def\myscale#1#2{%
   \tmpnum=#1 \the\tmpnum
   \loop
      \ifnum\tmpnum<#2
         \advance\tmpnum by1
         \quad\the\tmpnum
      \repeat
}
```

Using eTeX extension and axpandable solution:

```
\def\myscale#1#2{#1%
   \ifnum#1<#2 \space \expandafter\myscale\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}\fi
}
```

Edit: The third version adds the features described by jfbu in the comment below. I.e. the parameters are evaluated first and the nested `\if...\fi` is solved.

```
\def\myscale#1#2{\expandafter\myscaleA\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1\expandafter}%
                                      \expandafter{\the\numexpr#2}% evaluate params
}
\def\myscaleA#1#2{#1\ifnum#1<#2 \space \myscaleB{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}\fi}
\def\myscaleB#1\fi{\fi \expandafter\myscaleA\expandafter#1}
```

Comment: Compare egreg's solution with this. It is typical that LaTeX users generate overcomplicated codes. And such overcomplicated code is very often in LaTeX packages.

Comment: @wipet egreg's solution accounts for more possibilities; and yours does not either accepts `\count`'s without adding extra spaces in the output; and your `\numexpr` based solution does not allow expressions in `#2` like `2*6` and furthermore you nest many `\if...\fi` which egreg's solution avoids, although I agree that his `\@gobble/\@firstofone` could be changed into something slightly faster (through putting all the load on the executed once final branch). And  `egreg` is no typical LaTeX user. Typical LaTeX users do not generate code at all.

Comment: @jfbu I think teasing each other a bit should be allowed no? Plus all the speed advantage you get out of plain TeX is lost while learning it :P

Comment: @wipet I realize that when you first posted your answer, the one of `cmhughes` which contained almost identical code (for the non expandable loop) had been deleted already (I don't know why). About your third version: for optimization of expansion, I would rather put the next iteration already after the `\fi`, and in the case test fails indicating termination, then gobble what's after the `\fi` (five tokens or `{..}` with the suitable `\expandafter` already there. Thus, you need a gobble five but spare the specialized `\myscaleB`.

Answer (score 10):

With no package (but requiring e-TeX), a fully expandable solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myscale}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1=#2
    $#1$\expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\myscale@aux{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\myscale@aux}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>#2
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {\myscale@neg{#1}{#2}}%
  {\myscale@pos{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\myscale@neg}[2]{%
  $#1$\expandafter\myscale@neg@aux\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\myscale@neg@aux}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1<#2
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \space$#1$\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\expandafter\myscale@neg@aux\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1-1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\myscale@pos}[2]{%
  $#1$\expandafter\myscale@pos@aux\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\myscale@pos@aux}[2]{%
  \ifnum#1>#2
    \expandafter\@gobble
  \else
    \space$#1$\expandafter\@firstofone
  \fi
  {\expandafter\myscale@pos@aux\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\myscale{1}{6}

\myscale{1}{1}

\myscale{6}{1}

\myscale{1}{-1}

\edef\temp{\myscale{1}{6}}

\texttt{\meaning\temp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With optional arguments for different formatting (but not expandable, of course). The first optional argument to `\myscale` is the separator (default a space); the second argument is the separator between the last two items (default the same as the first argument); if specified, the third argument will be used between the last two of many items, the second if there are just two items (for the Oxford comma in the example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myscale}{O{~}oomm}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {
    \alain_myscale:nnnnn { #1 } { #1 } { #1 } { #4 } { #5 }
   }
   {
    \IfNoValueTF{#3}
     { \alain_myscale:nnnnn { #2 } { #1 } { #2 } { #4 } { #5 } }
     { \alain_myscale:nnnnn { #2 } { #1 } { #3 } { #4 } { #5 } }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_alain_myscale_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \alain_myscale:nnnnn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l_alain_myscale_seq
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #4 } { \int_compare:nTF { #4 > #5 } { -1 } { 1 } } { #5 }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l_alain_myscale_seq { $##1$ }
   }
  \seq_use:Nnnn \l_alain_myscale_seq { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\myscale{1}{6}

\myscale[, ]{1}{6}

\myscale[, ][ and ]{1}{6}

\myscale[, ][ and ][, and ]{1}{6}

\myscale{1}{1}

\myscale{6}{1}

\myscale{1}{-1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ooooh I *knew* there had to be something like `\int_step_inline:nnnn` – wasn't expecting it to be named that, though :)

Comment: @egreg in your first approach one can not use the macro with count variables (extra spaces) or with things like `\myscale{1+3}{2*8}`. For this reason,  `\xintSeq` (from package [xinttools](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint) expands first the `#1` and `#2` within a `\numexpr`. Furthermore it allows an optional argument while maintaining expandability.

Comment: @egreg about expandability (of which I am a big fan) as mentioned in my last comment: naturally it doesn't make much sense if the macro output is directly for typesetting. Only one exception comes to mind: constructing tabular rows from inside a tabular.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. The two arguments of `\myscale` can be any expressions that evaluate to numbers under TeX's and Lua's combined rules. If the macro's second argument is smaller than the first, nothing is printed.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\myscale}[2]{\directlua{%
     for i = #1, #2 do tex.print(i) end}}
\newcommand\myvar{1}
\begin{document}
\myscale{1}{6}            % integers from 1 to 6

\myscale{1+\myvar}{2*2^3} % integers from 2 to 16

\myscale{1}{0}            % nothing is printed
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: If *decreasing* arithmetic sequences are to be allowed (in which case the second argument of `\myscale` is smaller than the first), it's necessary to set the optional third argument of Lua's `for` loop -- which controls the step size of the increments -- to `-1`.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\myscale[2]{\directlua{%
         local incr = 1
         if #1 > #2 then incr = -1 end % set to -1 if decreasing sequence
         for i = #1, #2, incr do tex.print(i) end}}
\newcommand\myvar{1}  % a dummy macro
\begin{document}
\myscale{1}{6}

\myscale{math.log(1)}{2^3-\myvar}

\myscale{\myvar+2^math.exp(0)}{math.log(\myvar)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just… I just feel like this is cheating :)

Comment: @SeanAllred - I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying this is just too easy? Well, it's what a "real" programming language -- specifically, one with a built-in `for` loop -- is rather good at doing...

Comment: \*pouts\* It takes all the *fun* out of it :)

Comment: (To be clear, LuaTeX is really neat and a solution based thereupon should be listed here as well – if only to open a reader up to the possibilities.)

Answer (score 7):

interesting question, you can do this :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\myscale}[2]{%
  \foreach \index in {#1,...,#2}{\index\space\space}%
}
\begin{document}
\myscale{1}{6}

\myscale{9}{17}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! Does this example need any packages? It's best to post complete minimum working examples in these cases to avoid ambiguity :)

Comment: It can also display the ordered number of negative to positive numbers, `\myscale{-5}{5}. How to sort numbers from large to smaller?

Answer (score 7):

Using  `\whiledo` of package  `ifthen`:

> [image: MWE]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ifthen}    
    \newcounter{mycount}
    \newcommand{\myscale}[2]{
    \setcounter{mycount}{#1}
    \whiledo{\value{mycount}<#2}
    {\arabic{mycount}, \stepcounter{mycount}}%
    \arabic{mycount}.}
    \begin{document}
    \myscale{1}{6}\par
    \myscale{-4}{4}
    \end{document}
```

Or with the `forloop` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forloop}    
\newcounter{mycount}
\newcommand{\myscale}[2]{
\setcounter{mycount}{#1}
\forloop{mycount}{#1}{\value{mycount} < #2}%
{\arabic{mycount}, }%
\arabic{mycount}.}
\begin{document}
\myscale{1}{6}\par
\myscale{-4}{4}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for kicks, with `expl3`/`xparse`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \alain_range:nnN #1#2#3 {
  \seq_clear:N #3
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { #1 }
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { #2 }
  \int_while_do:nNnn \l_tmpa_int < \l_tmpb_int {
    \seq_push:NV #3 \l_tmpb_int
    \int_decr:N \l_tmpb_int
  }
  \seq_push:NV #3 \l_tmpb_int
}

\NewDocumentCommand \myscale {O{,~}m} {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {-} {#2}
  \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \seq_pop:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_tl
  \alain_range:nnN \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\myscale{3-6}

\myscale[ ]{3-6}

\myscale[ and ]{1-4}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `protected` rather than `nopar`. At least the recommendation is to leave `nopar` only for functions without arguments; at the same time, using `protected` except when the command is fully expandable.

Comment: @Manuel I'll have to trust you on that until I find the time to re-read the documentation :) I'm still not entirely sure what 'protected' means!

Comment: [l3styleguide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf), section 4 Code conventions, first and second paragraph.

Comment: @SeanAllred Challenge accepted. ;-)

Comment: @egreg I was *hoping* I could prompt you for some more `expl3` magic! :D